# how to access controls from class files in app code

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

How to access controls from class files in app code?

Markup:

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" Inherits="shoppingCart1.ShoppingPage" CodeFile="ShoppingPage.aspx.vb" %>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <title>ShoppingPage</title>
        <meta content="Microsoft Visual Studio .NET 7.1" name="GENERATOR">
        <meta content="Visual Basic .NET 7.1" name="CODE_LANGUAGE">
        <meta content="JavaScript" name="vs_defaultClientScript">
        <meta content="http://schemas.microsoft.com/intellisense/ie5" name="vs_targetSchema">
    </HEAD>
    <body>
        <form id="Form1" method="post" runat="server" name="Form1">
            <TABLE id="tblShopping" style="FONT-SIZE:10pt;FONT-FAMILY:verdana" borderColor="black"
                width="100%" cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0" border="1" runat="server">
                <tr style="FONT-SIZE:10pt;FONT-FAMILY:verdana;color:white;background-color:#336699;font-weight:bold;">
                    <td colspan="4">PRODUCT LIST</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    ***<td id="cellshoping" runat="server" colspan="4" width="100%"></td>***
                </tr>
                <tr>
                </tr>
            </TABLE>
        </form>
    </body>
</HTML>
```

ShoppingCart.vb In App_Code Folder

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Configuration

Public Class ShoppingCart
    Public Sub bindData()
        Dim con As New SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True")
        Dim objDA As SqlDataAdapter
        Dim myRow As SqlDataReader
        Dim comd As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM products", con)
        con.Open()
        myRow = comd.ExecuteReader()
        Dim strRowGen As String = ""
        While myRow.Read()
            strRowGen = strRowGen & "<TR>"
            strRowGen = strRowGen & "<TD>" & myRow.GetValue(0) & "</TD>"
            strRowGen = strRowGen & "<TD>" & myRow.GetValue(1) & "</TD>"
            strRowGen = strRowGen & "<TD>" & myRow.GetValue(2) & "</TD>"
            strRowGen = strRowGen & "<TD><a href='#' onclick=""javascript:document.Form1.action='ShoppingPage.aspx?Actn=Add&itemId=" & myRow.GetValue(0) & "';document.Form1.submit();"">Add To Cart</TD>"
            strRowGen = strRowGen & "</TR>"
            **cellshoping**.InnerHtml = strRowGen
        End While
    End Sub
End Class
```

I get an error at `cellshoping.InnerHtml` **"cellshoping is not declared"**...how to access user controls from class files in app code ??

**ADDED ASPX CODE BEHIND**

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Configuration


Namespace shoppingCart1

Partial Class ShoppingPage
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
#Region " Web Form Designer Generated Code "

    'This call is required by the Web Form Designer.
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()> Private Sub InitializeComponent()

End Sub
Protected WithEvents Label1 As System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label
Protected WithEvents Label2 As System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label
Protected WithEvents Label3 As System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label
Protected WithEvents txtNK As System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox
Protected WithEvents txtCF As System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox
Protected WithEvents txtHA As System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox
Protected WithEvents dtGrdProducts As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGrid


Private Sub Page_Init(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Init
    'CODEGEN: This method call is required by the Web Form Designer
    'Do not modify it using the code editor.
    InitializeComponent()
End Sub

#End Region
Private Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'Put user code to initialize the page here
    'Load data by calling function bindData()
            Dim sCart = New ShoppingCart
            If Not Page.IsPostBack Then

                cellshoping.InnerHtml = sCart.bindData()
            End If
    Dim strQty As Integer
    Dim proId As String
    Dim delId As String

    delId = Request.QueryString("delItemId")
    proId = Request.QueryString("itemId")
        '------ Following portion act as controller where code is written as
        '------ per the action from the request of the pages like Add To Cart,
        '------ Update Cart & Delete Cart
    strQty = 1
    If Request.QueryString("Actn") <> "" Then
        If Request.QueryString("Actn").Equals("Add") Then
                    If Request.QueryString("itemId") <> "" Then
                        AddToSession(proId, strQty)
                        Response.Redirect("./ShoppingCart.aspx")
                    End If
        ElseIf Request.QueryString("Actn").Equals("Del") Then
            If Request.QueryString("delItemId") <> "" Then
                Session.Remove(delId)
                Response.Redirect("./ShoppingCart.aspx")
            End If
        ElseIf Request.QueryString("Actn").Equals("Update") Then
            If Request.QueryString("itemUpId") <> "" And Request.QueryString("quantity") <> "" Then
                If IsNumeric(Request.QueryString("itemUpId")) Then
                    updateCart(Request.QueryString("itemUpId"), Request.QueryString("quantity"))
                    Response.Redirect("./ShoppingCart.aspx")
                Else
                    Response.Redirect("./ShoppingCart.aspx")
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub AddToSession(ByVal strProduct As String, ByVal intQty As Integer)
    If Not Session(strProduct) Is Nothing Then
        Session.Add(strProduct, CInt(Session(strProduct)) + intQty)
    Else
        Session.Add(strProduct, intQty)
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub updateCart(ByVal strProduct As String, ByVal qty As Integer)
    If Not Session(strProduct) Is Nothing Then
        Session.Add(strProduct, CInt(qty))
    End If
End Sub

End Class
End Namespace
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the ShoppingCart class is referenced somewhere in the page's code-behind and the BindData() method is called from that code, you have a few choices:

1) Pass a reference to the page to the shopping cart's bind data method.

2) Return the data from the BindData() method to the page so that it can update the data in the page appropriately.

3) You could access HttpContext.Current.Handler and cast that to an instance of your page.

My recommendation, especially if you want to use the class in other pages, is to either create an interface that has a method that can be used to update the data and use options 1 or 3, or implement option 2.

Here is an example of how you would change the code to implement and interface.

The interface:

```
Public Interface IShoppingCartPage
    Sub UpdateData(sCartContents As String)
End Interface
```

The page codebeghind (partial):

```
Public Class ShoppingPage
    Implements IShoppingCartPage

    Public Sub UpdateData(sCartContents As String) Implements IShoppingCartPage.UpdateData
        cellshopping.innerHtml = sCartContents
    End Sub
End Class
```

And finally, the modified shopping cart class (note the use of the stringbuilder class, which will be much more efficient than the string concat in the question):

```
Public Class ShoppingCart
    Public Sub bindData(oPage As IShoppingCartPage)
        Using con As New SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True")
            Using comd As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM products", con)
                con.Open()
                Using oReader As SqlDataReader = comd.ExecuteReader()
                    Dim sbHTML As New System.Text.StringBuilder(5000)
                    While oReader.Read()
                        sbHTML.Append("<TR>")
                        sbHTML.Append("<TD>").Append(oReader.GetValue(0)).Append("</TD>")
                        sbHTML.Append("<TD>").Append(oReader.GetValue(1)).Append("</TD>")
                        sbHTML.Append("<TD>").Append(oReader.GetValue(2)).Append("</TD>")
                        sbHTML.Append("<TD><a href='#' onclick=""javascript:document.Form1.action='ShoppingPage.aspx?Actn=Add&itemId=").Append(oReader.GetValue(0)).Append("';document.Form1.submit();"">Add To Cart</TD>")
                        sbHTML.Append("</TR>")
                    End While

                    oPage.UpdateData(sbHTML.ToString())
                End Using
            End Using
            con.Close()
        End Using
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: competent_tech you may want to make your response to him more user friendly so to speak.. I do not think he will understand what it is that you just wrote..in all due respect..

Comment: kindly elaborate..as @DJKRAZE said...i did not understand what to do exactly.

Comment: hello...kindly explain..point me to some tutorial or if you are free ,kindly help me.

Comment: I have updated the answer with specific code to show the necessary changes. I have also modified the answer to resolve issues with the database connection being left open and resources not being properly disposed.

Answer (score 0):

Why not have your method return a string?

```
Public Function bindData() as String
    Dim con As New SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True")
    Dim objDA As SqlDataAdapter
    Dim myRow As SqlDataReader
    Dim comd As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM products", con)
    con.Open()
    myRow = comd.ExecuteReader()
    Dim strRowGen As String = ""
    While myRow.Read()
        strRowGen = strRowGen & "<TR>"
        strRowGen = strRowGen & "<TD>" & myRow.GetValue(0) & "</TD>"
        strRowGen = strRowGen & "<TD>" & myRow.GetValue(1) & "</TD>"
        strRowGen = strRowGen & "<TD>" & myRow.GetValue(2) & "</TD>"
        strRowGen = strRowGen & "<TD><a href='#' onclick=""javascript:document.Form1.action='ShoppingPage.aspx?Actn=Add&itemId=" & myRow.GetValue(0) & "';document.Form1.submit();"">Add To Cart</TD>"
        strRowGen = strRowGen & "</TR>"            
    End While
    Return strRowGen

End Sub
```

Then you can call it from your page

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
   'Set innerHtml here
   'cellshoping.InnerHtml = ShoppingCart.bindData()
End Sub
```

Comment: ok..i am using your technique..when i try to run the page it says `"'bindData' is not a member of 'shoppingCart1.ShoppingCart'.
"`